# Google Play Service and com.google.process.gapps has stopped

Tags: google-play-services

The following message keeps appearing on my Asus tablet model K01A screen about every three seconds.

> Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped

> Unfortunately, the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped

I tried to update the Google apps but it doesn't work.

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the Store and Google services from apps ( revert to original ) Then update again

Answer (score 0):

1. Simplest solution - reboot your device. This solves most of the common issues
2. Try updating Google Play Services to the latest version
3. If that doesn't work, clear the Google Play Services cache. You can do this by:

   1. Going to `Settings > Apps`
   2. Swipe to `All apps` (or select `Show System` from the overflow menu at the top-right corner if your device is rooted and you're running CyanogenMod) and then
   3. Scroll down to “Google Play Services” app
   4. Open the app details and tap on the “Force stop” button
   5. Then, tap on the “Clear cache” button
4. If that doesn't work either, try clearing the Google Services Framework cache

Comment: try S Rao's method in SAFE MODE, because the error notification may not let you do it in normal mode.